# Why button does not reflect Action' NAME property?

Tags: java, swing, action, modal-dialog, jbutton

I suppose button should has "Close" title in the code below, but it has not:

```
public class Test_Actions extends JDialog 
{   
    private AbstractAction closeAction = new AbstractAction() 
    {       
        {
            putValue("NAME", "Close");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            Test_Actions.this.setVisible(false);
            Test_Actions.this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(Test_Actions.this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }       
    };

    public Test_Actions() 
    {       
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello world");

        JButton button = new JButton(closeAction);
        //button.setText("Text");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException 
    {
        final Test_Actions dialog = new Test_Actions();
        dialog.setModal(true);

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }       
        });

        System.out.println("Here");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Action.NAME` instead of `"NAME"`.

The [value of this constant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.swing.Action.NAME) is actually `"Name"` so you could use that as well, but as you see it's easy to get it wrong.